# build Filter using Django RestFramework and Angular fronted

Tags: django, angular

i try build a filter for my fronted Angular from Django backend, or how i can build filter using restframework_filter please people help , i have this in the backend

viewset.py

```
from snippets.models import Snippet
from .serializers import SnippetSerializer
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.decorators import action
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from django_filters  import rest_framework as filters


class SnippetFilter(filters.FilterSet):

    class Meta:
        model = Snippet
        fields = {
            'title': ['icontains'],
            'created': ['iexact', 'lte', 'gte'],
        }


class SnippetViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Snippet.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SnippetSerializer
    filterset_class = SnippetFilter

    @action(methods=['get'], detail=False)
    def newest(self, request):
        newest = self.get_queryset().order_by('created').last()
        serializer = self.get_serializer_class()(newest)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I create my filters explicitly.  For example following code will produce `snippets/?snippet_field_lte=<number>` and `snippets/?another_field=<number>` endpoints.

```
class SnippetFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    snippet_field_lte = NumberFilter(name="snippet_field", lookup_expr="lte")
    another_field = NumberFilter(name="another_field", lookup_expr="exact")

    class Meta:
        model = Snippet
        fields = ["snippet_field_lte", ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same situations (Django backend, Angular frontend). I'm not using restframework filter directly though, but, you could try the following that will allow you to make any type of query with your model as described in the official [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#field-lookups)

```py
class MyModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MyModelSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        results = super(MyModelViewSet, self).get_queryset()
        # Instead of explicit property calling in the filter
        for key, value in self.request.GET.items():
            # I use a key/value pair from dictionary obtained from request.GET
            results = results.filter(**{key: value}) # <-- this is the "trick"
            # Then, I return the filtered queryset
            return results
        # if no parameter were provided in the request, it will return .all()
        return results
```

That being done and assuming your model has properties `name` and `age` you could make the following `GET` requests:

- localhost:8000/`mymodel?name=Jonh%20Doe`  --> Name exactly "Jonh Doe"
- localhost:8000/`mymodel?name__icontains=Jonh%20D`  --> Name Contains "Jonh D"
- localhost:8000/`mymodel?age__gte=20` --> Age is greater than 20
- localhost:8000/ --> Return all objects from MyModel